# Getting a 404 with NodeJS Request to Tesla API

Tags: node.js, express, request, http-status-code-404, tesla

I am trying to retrieve my vehicle's data from the public Tesla API (https://www.teslaapi.io/vehicles/state-and-settings). I'm using NodeJS, with the Request and Express packages, I'm able to retrieve the initial accessToken, as well as the Vehicle ID number. However, when I'm trying to use these two values to actually make a GET request for the data, I keep getting a 404 error. I've been debugging for hours and am honestly not sure why. I hit the same endpoint in postman and get the correct response, any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, how can I avoid having to make subsequent requests inside the previous callback, would Async be the way to go? Thanks!

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000
var path = require("path");


var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");


var accessToken;

var request = require('request').defaults({
    headers: {
        "x-tesla-user-agent": "TeslaApp/3.4.4-350/fad4a582e/android/8.1.0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel XL Build/OPM4.171019.021.D1; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"}
    });




app.get("/", function(req, resp){

   /* GET ACCESS TOKEN */
     request({
       url: 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token',
       method: 'POST',
       json: true,
       gzip: true,
       body: {
         "grant_type": 'password',
         "client_id": '81527cff06843c8634fdc09e8ac0abefb46ac849f38fe1e431c2ef2106796384',
         "client_secret":'c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3',
         "email": 'MYUSERNAME',
         "password": 'MYPASSWORD'
       },
      }, function(err, res, body) {
       accessToken = body.access_token;

            /* GET THE VEHICLE ID NUMBER */
            request({
            url: 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" } 

           }, function(err, res, body) {
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        var vehicleID = parsedBody.response[0].id;
        resp.render('index', {hi: accessToken} );
        var vehicleIDString = vehicleID.toString();
        var finalURL = 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/' + vehicleIDString + '/vehicle_data';


            /*  Get Vehicle Data    (THIS IS GIVING 404) */
            request({

                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/' + vehicleIDString + '/vehicle_data',
                        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" } 

            }, 
                function(err, res, body){    
                console.trace();

            });//END GET VEHICLE DATA

      });//END VEHICLE ID NUMBER REQUEST


     });//END ACCESS TOKEN REQUEST

});




/* HIT ANY ENDPOINT WE WANT */







app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Example app listening on port ${port}!') } )
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it's because `parsedBody` doesn't exist which throws off the URL, and since the URL is wrong and doesn't exist, you get the 404.. try to change this part `var vehicleID = parsedBody.response[0].id;` to this `var vehicleID = body.response[0].id;` ...Right before that line (`var vehicleID = ...`) you could `console.log("parsedBody", parsedBody); console.log("body", body);` to confirm this theory..

Comment: Sorry that line was accidentally deleted when removing console.log()'s in the initial post. Indeed parsedBody did exist, original code updated. Still can't figure out why the 404 :(

Comment: Try looking at `request-promise`!

Comment: Not sure but maybe you're not setting the response correctly or either the URI you're making is incorrect?

Comment: I believe that all of the that is correct. I printed out the final URL beforehand to verify, and it's the same one being called in postman that's returning the correct response. I honestly am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had a similar error (404) with TeslaJS in NodeRed and it was due to Tesla having changed the vehicleID value (id_s field).

The "vehicles" command is still working then it is possible to retrieve the new id_s values and pass it to the following commands.
When using this new id_s, the error disappears and the problem is solved.

Hope this can help some other peoples with same problem...

A good practice would probably to select id_s using VIN value which will not change over the time...

Comment: Thank you very much Philippe! I had the same problem. After retrieving the new id_s now it's working again. I noticed that also the vehicle_id did not change, so you could rely on that other than the VIN.

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling onto some other thread, I realized that the original documentation was incorrect, and instead of **id**, it should've been **id_s**. So both the fault of subpar documentation, as well as my poor attention to the details. Thanks!!

https://github.com/timdorr/tesla-api/issues/53